# Azure DevOps YAML how to being notified about new task version

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-yaml-pipelines

In the graphical build editor there was a hint if there is a new version of a build task:

[image: GraphicalEditor]

Is there any equivalent in the YAML editor?

[image]

Or is there any other option to find out, if there is a new task version available (besides searching the documentation)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Tasks are versioned, and you must specify the major version of the
> task used in your pipeline. This can help to prevent issues when new
> versions of a task are released.Tasks are typically backwards
> compatible, but in some scenarios you may encounter unpredictable
> errors when a task is automatically updated.
>
> **When a new minor version is released (for example, 1.2 to 1.3), your build or release will automatically use the new version.** However, if
> a new major version is released (for example 2.0), your build or
> release will continue to use the major version you specified until you
> edit the pipeline and manually change to the new major version. **The
> build or release log will include an alert that a new major version is
> available.**
>
> *[Source Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/tasks?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml&viewFallbackFrom=vsts#task-versions)*

If you are using a deprecated task, you will also find this kind of info in log such as:

[image]

Even in classic editor, not every task was a hint if there is a new version, it's more related to two points:    1. Task Author 2. If old task is deprecated.

[image]

> However, if I do the same with PowerShell@2to PowerShell@1, I get no
> warning

Cause you could use either powershell version 1 or version 2 even though the higher version of one task is more recommended.

Besides, if you use other shortcuts in YAML without version specificed, it resolve to the PowerShell@2 task:

```
- powershell:  # inline script
  workingDirectory:  #
  displayName:  #
  failOnStderr:  #
  errorActionPreference:  #
  ignoreLASTEXITCODE:  #
  env:  # mapping of environment variables to add
```

You could also take a look at this similar issue: [How do I specify "always latest" task version in YAML?](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/issues/2582)

Comment: Deprecation is one thing, but the "flag" icon hints about new major versions being available even if the one currently in use is not deprecated. But I guess I just have to either proactively check the docs and release notes, or reactively wait till something appears in the task logs or even till the pipelines start failing. :-(

Answer (score 0):

You task version is specified after `@` so `DevEnvBuild@1` means you have version 1 of this task. So please change to `DevEnvBuild@2` and you are good to go.

And in terms of being notified about new version. I think there is no out of the box solution, but if I use version `1` I have a warning:

[image]

Which disappear in version `2`

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I know how to change to a new version, but I need a practical way to find out *if* there is a new version.

Comment: Sorry I missed your main point. I just edited an answer. I don't think so. However, I'm being notified that for some reason `@1` is deprecated. Do you see the same in your YAML editor?

Comment: I see the same warning when I change `DevEnvBuild@2` to `DevEnvBuild@1`. However, if I do the same with `PowerShell@2`to `PowerShell@1`, I get no warning.

Comment: Well, it is probably up to task author to make task deprecated or no. And new task now always means that old one is deprecated as you see this with `PowerShell` task.